# how to find GCP services interdependencies

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Before I can use a particular service, I have to enable the API in my Google project. Sometimes when I do this, more services are enabled than the one I specified. for example, enabling cloudfunctions service actually enabling multiple APIs in the background like pubsub, storage etc.

I followed this article to find the service dependencies https://binx.io/blog/2020/10/03/how-to-find-google-cloud-platform-services-dependencies/. The command output in the above article shows the dependent services as below

```
gcloud services list \
   --available --format json | \
jq --arg service cloudfunctions.googleapis.com \
    'map(select(.config.name == $service)| 
        { 
          name:      .config.name, 
          dependsOn: .dependencyConfig.dependsOn
        }
    )'
```

the result is:

```
{
  "name": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
  "dependsOn": [
    "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "logging.googleapis.com",
    "pubsub.googleapis.com",
    "source.googleapis.com",
    "storage-api.googleapis.com",
    "storage-component.googleapis.com"
  ]
}
```

when i am executing this command, i am not getting the output as above. the  ""dependsOn":" section is showing as "null"
below is the output of the same command when i executed in cloudshell.

```
  {
    "name": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "dependsOn": null
  }
]
```

does there any alternate way to identify the service interdependencies. can someone help on this please

Comment: Edit your question and show the problem you are having using that article as your starting commands. Stating **not giving the output as advertised** is not a problem statement. Show what you tried, what data was returned and what you expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see the **dependencyConfig** section output by the command on my system.

When I look at the API [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services/list), the [Service](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services#Service) resource does not contain the section **dependencyConfig**.

It appears that Google has removed that item from the API that the command **gcloud services list** uses to display service information.